# SQLite error on belongs_to/has_many association in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite, associations

I have two models with the following associations:

- A user has many projects.
- A project belongs to a user.

User model (user.rb):

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :projects
   attr_accessible :available, :department, :name, :skills, :title, :photo
 end
```

Project model (project.rb):

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => :user_id
  attr_accessible :project_name
end
```

Foreign key migration file:

```
class AddForeignKeyToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :user_id, :integer
  end
end
```

When I call `<%= @user.projects %>` I get this error message:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: projects.user_id: SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects"  WHERE "projects"."user_id" = 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You added the foreign key to the wrong table. It should be in `projects`, not in `users`:

```
class AddForeignKeyToProjects < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :projects, :user_id, :integer
  end
end
```

Since you are sticking to the convention, you don't have to specify the foreign key in your `Project` model. This should be enough:

```
belongs_to :user
```